# Why don't global variables defined by imported functions change?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-import

I have a function in a file:

```
global_value = 100    #defualt
def function(new_value):
    global global_value
    print(global_value,new_value)
    global_value = new_value
```

function() takes in a value,compares it to global_value and then sets the global_value to new_value.

I am not using this function within the file, rather importing it.

(file2:)

```
from file import *
value = input("enter value")
function(value)
print(global_value)
```

The function works correctly however at the end global_value is shown to be equal to 100 (it's defualt value), not the input.
What can I do to make global_value change in file2 as well?

thanks.

Comment: `:` is missing after `range(5)`

Comment: Apart from the missing `:` your code works fine when I try it.

Comment: @khelwood What's the value of `global_value` after running that code? I get 100, and I think that's what the question is about.

Comment: Each turn through the loop correctly reports to me the value from the previous iteration and the value entered in this iteration. If there's some later step where reading global_value gives a different value, that code should be part of the question, along with the output.

Comment: yes it seems like every time i run the function global_value is redefined with its defualt value.

Comment: @yonatanstrichman Add `print(global_value) after `for` loop so it will be clearer what do you mean. No need a `for` loop at all to illustrate your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables in Python aren't really global; they are scoped to a particular module.

After you execute `from file import *`, you have *two* variables; `file.global_variable`, which is the one that `file.function` updates, and a new `global_variable` in the current module which is *initialized* using the original value of `file.global_variable`, but is never updated by `function`.

Each function contains a reference to the global scope in which the function was *defined*. In Python 2 it's `file.function.func_globals`; in Python 3 its `tmp.function.__globals__`. That is the scope in which any of its "global" variables are looked up, not the scope in which the function is *called*.

Add a plain `import file` to your second file, then run `print(global_variable, file.global_variable)` to see the difference.